# Android WebView Error - Access denied(policy_denied)

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app and I use a Webview for a section, but I notice my webview doesn't appear correctly now.

Instead this error appears on screen:

Access denied(policy_denied)

You system policy has denied access to the requested url.

Works fine in the emulator.

Anyone have any ideas where I should be looking to solve this?

Regards,
Sally.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for 'Access denied(policy_denied)' is your carrier blocking the particular address. It can be a firewall or anything in between your app and the web server. If you are on 3G try switching to WiFi or if you are at workplace test it on home network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! really appreciate it, on the emulator it works fine but on mobile devices it appears with the error, should i contact my hosting company?. But wait the link works when I access it via my laptop....weird

Comment: Ask your IT department if they have  installed some filtering software.

Comment: @Sarah.. are you using the same wifi from both your system and phone on whihc you are testing? your system is on wife or LAN by any chance? try to access the same link from phone browser to see if your netwrk is not blocking it?

Comment: well its actually my friends who are testing on their wifi connections, all getting the same error, ive no device to test on :/

Comment: perhaps their phones have an admin app on them that is blocking whatever page you are trying to load.

Comment: I find it's odd as I've never had this problem before

Comment: I think it might be something to do with my hosting, I have contacted them about it

Comment: they couldnt help, i can access the site on my wifi and 3g network, my other friend can not....weird